# Pyscripter doesn't work with Abaqus Python

Tags: python, pyscripter, abaqus

How to install Pyscripter for using with Abaqus finite element program? I don't want to use Abaqus PDE. The pyscripter works ok on it's own, but it shows Import Error "only" for modules related to Abaqus finite element software. I have directed the Python path to Abaqus Python executable, however it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible. You can only import abaqus modules when python is run from the abaqus executable, i.e. by issuing the 'abaqus python' command. I don't know why this is, perhaps someone else can enlighten us. 
I didn't want to use the abaqus PDE either and spent ages trying to get around it. I have resorted to writing the code in another environment and using a command prompt to run it with 'abaqus python ###.py' etc.

Comment: I'd assume it relates to licensing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use any other IDE with Abaqus related packages at all.
If you don't want to use the Abaqus PDE you can write your code in whatever editor you like and just use the run script commands in Abaqus to run it.
or you can use the command prompt to run your code without lunching abaqus gui like :

```
abaqus cae noGUI=scriptname.py
```